# effect of charge surface on one point

Tags: electric-fields, potential

I would like to calculate the effect of charge surface on one point in a ionic solution and obtain the value of potential U:

```
   |                      |
   |       ionic solution |
   |                      |
   |  charged             |
   |  surface             |
   |                      |
   |  +|                  |
   |  +|    measurement   |
   |  +|    point: . <----|------------  ^
   |  +|<---------->      |              | 
   |  +|  distance d      |              |  U
   |______________________|              |
                                         |
                                         |   __ref_ 0V_
```

I know how to calculate if I had only the charged surface but how do I take in account the ionic solution ?

thanks a lot

Comment: maybe its just me, but i cannot fully read your "sketch"

Comment: @DomDoe I modified it, is it better ?

Comment: It depends on the shape of the container and how the liquid behaves. The charged surface will polarize the liquid. In the simplest cases the polarization of the medium has zero divergence except on its boundaries so one may determine the potential by adding up contributions due to surface charge on the boundary (here, including the charged surface and walls of the container). But if the liquid is not homogeneous (so its permittivity varies with position) then there may be polarization charges inside the liquid volume as well.

Comment: In any case, determining that polarization charge distribution is not practically possible to do on paper. It may be possible to use some computer program that can solve the boundary value problem.

Comment: @JánLalinský yes, the liquid is "polarized", so maybe I should calculated as temporal evolution, with differential equation but I don't know how to do do that...

Comment: If the charge on the charged surface doesn't change or changes very slowly, this falls into the realm of electrostatics. If you want to focus on physics, learn as much as possible on that subject. If you just want the result for given permittivity and container geometry, search for some software that can calculate EM fields for boundary value problems.

Comment: Why do you want to calculate the potential in that point? Potential is easily influenced by other nearby bodies as well (such as measuring probe), so it may be that calculating the contribution just due to the ionic solution may not be that useful.